# Connection Error try again later - Magento connect not working

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect-manager

I am struggling from last week to install an extension using Magento connect, but it is not working so far. When I tried to installed SMTP Pro, the progress circle keeps running for atleast 5 mins and thereafter gives error "Connection Error try again later". So I tried to install another extension but no one getting installed. So definitely there is a problem with Magento connect manager.

I tried all the solution available here or anywhere on the internet but nothing is serving the purpose.

Just wanted to know if there is any option to trace the problem.

Comment: firstly check error log file.in root folder  and if not enable error log please enable it. from developer tab ->log setting  enable it 

check public_html/var/log/exception.log file

Comment: clear cache .. did you move file to another server ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look almost 15 days to find out the problem, I installed a fresh copy of Magento and fresh database and perform the test to install extension and that gave me exact error. So finally my doubt gone to Server Hosting. After detailed check I found my ports 80, 465, 587 were blocked due to some malicious file from other website. I just removed the file and requested to unblock the port and all has started working for me.

This has sorted out my problem with SMTP Pro too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....