# Magento Connect Manager Not working - Returns Error Page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect-manager

How can I solve magento connect manager not working at my back end, its return 404 Error. I have checked `system - > configuration -> advance` : Its fine, And also tried `magento_cleanup_file`.

How can I clear this error.

Comment: please fire `yourbase_url/downloader` if its give you 404 then your downloader folder has not sufficient permission

Comment: check this once : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141011/connection-error-try-again-later-magento-connect-not-working/141033#141033

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/bXnFAoC.png

Answer (score 1):

please fire `yourbase_url/downloader` in browser ,if its give you 404 then your `downloader` folder in root does not have sufficient permission.

please give it to write permission and may be your problem would solve.

Comment: sorry, i couldn't get you,

Comment: at root you find downloader folder give it to write permission

Comment: after i gave write oermission, still not working

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/bXnFAoC.png

Comment: Does any other solutions ::

Comment: in your browser fire `your_base_url/downloader`

Comment: when i click magento connect manager go to this url : http://abcd.in/downloader/?return=http%3A%2F%2Fhygienicsolution.in%2Findex.php%2Fadmin%2F    whn i remove

Comment: http://abcd.in?return=http%3A%2F%2Fhygienicsolution.in%2Findex.php%2Fadmin%2F  , its also error

Comment: when i remove downloder from my url, its redirect to my site

Comment: http://hygienicsolution.in/?return=http%3A%2F%2Fhygienicsolution.in%2Findex.php%2Fadmin%2F